# What are ubuntu/juju image metadata

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack, metadata

Could someone explain me what this page wants to say? i really dont get what and mainly why it is written there what is there.

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/howto-privatecloud.html

Ive own HW, with MAAS, Juju and Openstack deployment.

What are the metadata they talk about there? Do i need them?

Before i bootstrap juju? | before i boot VMs at nova-compute? Is it somehow related to api-metadata service?